# How to use a variable as a field name in mongodb-native findAndModify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In this code that uses the mongodb-native driver I'd like to increase the value of the field which I specify in a separate variable. The problem is that the field name in the $inc clause will be 'variable' in this case, not the contents of the variable. In the query part the variable selected works as expected and finds the correct id.

```
var selected = 'id_of_the_selected_one';
var variable = 'some_string';
collection.findAndModify(
     {_id : selected}, 
     {},
     {$inc : {variable : 1}},
     {new : true, upsert : true},
     function(err, autoincrement) { /* ... */ }
);
```

How should I do it so that instead of the word 'variable' there will be the contents of the variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the key of another variable to its value and pass that as an object. Note of *action*:

```
var selected = 'id_of_the_selected_one';
var variable = 'some_string';
var action = {};
action[variable] = 1; // the value

collection.findAndModify(
    {_id : selected}, 
    {}, 
    {$inc : action}, 
    {new : true, upsert : true}, 
    function(err, autoincrement) { /* ... */ }
); // Same as {$inc: {'some_string': 1} }
```