# MongoDB increment number in subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoskin

My mongoDB document looks like this:

```
   {
      valOne: "one",
      valTwo: "two",
      valThree: {
                  threeOne: 0,
                  threeTwo: 0
                }
    }
```

i would like to increment either "threeOne" or "threeTwo" depending on the user request.

My code so far:

```
var whichFieldToUpdate = request.body.field; //can be either threeOne or threeTwo
var id = new BSON.ObjectID(request.body.id); //contains document id

db.collection('name').update({_id: id}, {$inc: { ?????? } },
  function(err, result) {

});
```

???? should be something like this: `{$inc: {valThree: {whichFieldToUpdate : 1 } }`

Comment: use the dot notation to access subdocuments {$inc: {'valThree.threeOne' : 1 }

Comment: yeah i go that thx. but the problem is that threeOne changes depending on the response and {$inc: {'valThree.' + whichFieldToUpdate : 1 } doesn't seem to be working

Comment: do it with an if statement instead of trying to put the whichFieldToUpdate dynamically

Comment: you already have a question on how to use variables as field names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133912/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-field-name-in-mongodb-native-findandmodify - I don't know if it works, but give it a try :)

Comment: yes perfect thank you. I think this way is mush nicer that with if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var field = 'valThree.' + request.body.field;
var inc =  {};
inc[field] = 1;

db.collection('name').update({_id: id}, {$inc: inc } },
  function(err, result) {

});
```